# Случайно сделал Revert для некоторых файлов с изменениями. Как восстановить эти изменения?

Tags: git

Всем привет!

Случайно сделал Revert для некоторых файлов, где были новые изменения (коммита не было). 
Как восстановить эти изменения?

Comment: если коммита не было, то git их не сохраняет. Поэтому, средствами git их не восстановить. Возможно, их можно восстановить средствами операционной системы.

Comment: если работа производилась в IDE производителя Jetbrains, то стоит заглянуть в local history.

Comment: @vechestva, делали "git add" для этих файлов? Если да, то восстановить можно.

Comment: Эти файлы уже были в проекте, я их просто модифицировал.

Comment: @vechestva, это я понял. Вопрос в том, добавляли ли вы изменения в индекс командой git add.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Можно ли вернуть несохраненные файлы после \`git checkout .\`?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/424315/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-git-checkout). Как верно замечает в комментариях dzhioev, если `git add` было, восстановить можно; решение есть в вопросе, к которому отмечаю дубликат.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: несмотря на возможно общее решение, вопросы то разные.

Comment: @KromStern: я сильно подозреваю, что речь идет о reset, а не revert.

Comment: @NickVolynkin предлагаю не подозревать (решение для одного ТС), а отвечать (решение для всех кто по ссылкам сюда приходит).

Comment: @KromStern: т.е. написать про восстановление именно после revert? Надо подумать, будут ли хоть какие-то отличия. ) Ладно, пока что сниму флаг.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Если есть такая проблема, то нужно и решения для нее )